# .htaccess mod_rewrite for http://subdomain.domain.com to http://subdomain.com

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I looked at a number of q/a pairs and couldn't quite find this specific question. The subdomain in question is an add-on domain to the primary domain on the server, allowing the subdomain to appear as its own unique website. For example, lets call the add-on (sub) domain 'subcontractor' and the (primary) domain 'general.' The url http://subcontractor.com functions as completely different website from http://general.com; however, some generated links (that I don't have direct control over) expose the connection and bring the visitor to http://subcontractor.general.com/some/page123 where I would prefer it to display http://subcontractor.com/some/page123. While these two urls lead to the same page, I don't want 'general' to displayed anywhere in the url in context with 'subcontractor.' I tried the following with no success:

```
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "(.*)"
RewriteRule "^/(.*)" "http://subcontractor.com/$1"
```

Assuming {HTTP_HOST} in this case to be http://subcontractor.general.com. Can you help me with a mod_rewrite that satisfies? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subcontractor.general.com$
RewriteRule ^(.+) http://general.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

`$1` is the back-reference to `(.+)`, which matches all the characters of the url path.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, Ben! I think was too specific with my example. I'm looking to redirect every page from general to subcontractor. http://subcontractor.general.com/any/page => http://subcontractor.com/any/page. 'General' (the primary domain) should _never_ be displayed in the URL. **subcontractor.general.com** should always become **subcontractor.com**

Comment: just updated the answer, all the url from `subcontractor.general.com` redirects to `general.com`